# Android unwanted border between views with shape background

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

I've got some Android views with XML shapes as backgrounds. The shapes are transparent with white borders.

However, when they render there is a 1 pixel greyish border that is visible between them.

What is causing this and how do I get rid of it?

**The problem:**
[image: zoomed]

**Close up:**
[image: zoomed]

**My layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**shape.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="@android:color/white" android:width="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: For me, that greyish border just shows up on the Android Studio designer and not on my device or emulator. Are you trying to get rid of it in the designer?

Comment: Interesting, this is appearing on my device. Those images were taken as a screen capture.

Comment: Not sure if relevant but I notice the lines are only visible if the underlying view has a different background color.

Comment: Definitely not on mine with API 26. Which API are you on and the device. Do you see it in emulation? I changed the underlying view to black to make it more pronounced if it is some sort of gap, but it still does not show.

Comment: It is showing on various devices, mostly API 23. It is not showing on an API 25 device.

Comment: Have you tried setting your LinearLayouts `layout_height` to `wrap_content`?